# LINQ to XML - Selecting with multiple attribute filters?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I was a long time user of **XmlTextReader** but after noting that the answer to every related question on here was **'use LINQ'** I decided to take the plunge, everything has been going well up until this point. I've been banging my head against this for a while, hopefully someone can help.

I have the following section in my document;

```
  <action_areas>
    <time_slice name="0 - 5" id="1">
      <action_area id="1">
        <aa_team id="1000">9</aa_team>
        <aa_team id="1001">7</aa_team>
      </action_area>
      <action_area id="2">
        <aa_team id="1000">5</aa_team>
        <aa_team id="1001">2</aa_team>
```

Due to the structure of the document I need "action_areas" to be the thing passed to the initial selection, ie;

```
 var stuff = from item in xDoc.Descendants("action_areas")
```

So the question is what statements do I follow that with so I can filter based on the `time_slice` name attribute AND the `action_area` id attribute AND the `aa_team` id attribute so I can ultimately get at the content contained in the `aa_team` element (9, 7, 5 and 2 in the above instance) with the `'select new'` statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string timeSliceToSearchFor = "0 - 5";
string actionAreaToSearchFor = "1";
string aaTeamIdToSearchFor = "1001";

// Returns 7
string value = xDoc .Descendants("action_areas")
                    .Elements("time_slice")
                    .Where(element => element.Attribute("name").Value == timeSliceToSearchFor)
                    .Elements("action_area")
                    .Where(element => element.Attribute("id").Value == actionAreaToSearchFor)
                    .Elements("aa_team")
                    .Where(element => element.Attribute("id").Value == aaTeamIdToSearchFor)
                    .Single().Value;
```